# How to shift column values on a single dataframe row (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

The database I'm working with looks something like this:

```
         C1        C2         C3

R1      Nan       Nan         2

R2      1         Nan        Nan

R3      2         2          Nan
```

and I wanted to copy and shift that last value in each cell to the others in its row, and have something like this:

```
         C1        C2         C3

R1       2         2          2

R2      1          1          1

R3      2         2           2
```

How can I do it? I'm new with Pandas and I would like some help

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)/[`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) the rows:

```
out = df.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1, downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
    C1  C2  C3
R1   2   2   2
R2   1   1   1
R3   2   2   2
```